# Creating a simple socket

Tags: php, sockets, cron, port, fwrite

I'm completely new to PHP sockets and I'm gonna use them for one simple purpose at the moment: I want to pass information between a *Cron Job* and the net one, and since my host prevents me from using `putenv`, this is the best solution I found.

Reading the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), this is what I tried to do:

```
$host = "localhost"; //or ssl://mydomain.com
$socket = fsockopen($host, 80, $no, $err,0);
if(!$err)
{
    var_dump(fputs($socket, "random text"));
    var_dump(filesize($socket));
    var_dump(fgets($socket, filesize($socket)));
    fclose($socket);
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
int(3)
NULL
bool(false)
```

So it seems that `fput` has success, but for some reason it does not actually write anything (same result with `fwrite` and `fread`.

---

UPDATE:

for anyone interested in that, I found out [another solution](https://www.mrwebmaster.it/php/curl-user-agent-random_12965.html) which uses [a completely different approach](https://www.wdb24.com/php-get-random-user-agent-function/).

Now I just have to test it out; if it does not work for any reason, I'm gonna proceed with peakle's solution

Comment: Why do you expect `filesize()` to return something meaningful for a socket? After all, a socket is not a file.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk even writing 11 it`fgets()` returns `false`

Comment: You seem to be confusing sockets with files. A socket is one half of a connection. When you have a connected socket whatever you write can only be read at the other end of the connection, not the same end. Similarly, the only data you can read is that which has been sent from the other end.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk I'd need help to understand how to implement the other end, and where to keep those data during the time between the cronjobs

Comment: Just store it in a file.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk do you mean the socket? At this point, which could be the advantages between that and storing the real data inside the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some errors on your script, like: zero timeout in fsockopen, provide `resource` to  `filesize` function, i fixed some them and if your server on `localhost` domain works fine it will be output correct response:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$socket = fsockopen($host, 80, $no, $err, 30);

if (!$err) {
    var_dump(fputs($socket, "random text"));

    while (!feof($socket)) {
        echo fgets($socket, 4096);
    }

    fclose($socket);
}
```

:)

Comment: It still soes not work. `fgets` keeps returning `false`

Comment: @Foxel do you want to use sockets for communication between some process without webserver? or for what? because i wrote solution to work with webserver :)
if first of all you want to use `putenv`  maybe best solution and more simple will be use writing to file? because using sockets it very complex area

Comment: I have a webserver (localhost by XAMPP and my domain from my hosting service), I would have preferred a socket just because creating a blank file just to store a line of data seemed a non-efficient solution to me

Comment: @Foxel example with socket solution: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php#108535, 
i highly recommend you something like dotenv for php due to the complexity of sockets: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv , i think it will a good choice to solve your problem

Comment: My host service has disabled `putenv`, will this library work anyway?

Comment: @Foxel out of box no :(  ,but  !!!! if you want to change this file dynamically you can do something like this:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/995bddf0ac1e3ff711c1820edff26386be3d581d

Comment: Thanks, I solved by creating a file on that same folder and accessing it at the very top of the script. Do you suggest to call this file `file.env` for some reason (like in your example) or a *.txt* is ok?

Comment: more conventional will be to name it `.env` ;)